# Authentication and Authorization to AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was reading up per subject matter and has a query on what is the best practice to handle user's authorization to AWS resources.

**Scenario:**

1. A 2-tiers windows application that access to AWS S3 and dynamoDB.
2. There are 2 groups of users - Admin and Normal User. Admin has read + write access, and Normal User has just the read access.
3. I'm trying to see if I could avoid a 3-tiers design. At such, I would like to access AWS resources directly from my application. In another word, I do not access AWS resources thru web services (that could do my user authorization check there).

**Design:**

1. I uses Web Identity Federation (google) to authenticate user and uses STS to get temporary credentials.
2. I've created 2 IAM Roles - AdminRole (with write+read policy) and UserRole (with read policy).
3. At this point, my thoughts are stuck on what is the best practice and securely choose which role to assume from my application.

**Solution 1:**

1. Create a UserRole table in dynamoDb with UserId and Role attributes.
2. After user has authenticated with google, I'll check the UserRole table against the userid returned from google to get the role of this user. Assuming I've pre-setup all the user's roles in the table.
3. I do not want to hardcode or expose my AWS secret key onto my app, but for the above execution, I've created a secret key with a role and policy only to the [UserRole] table.
4. At this point, I would know which role to assume from my app when I get the temporary credential using STS.

However, with the above solution, I see that there is one security loophole. If someone is able to get hold of my application id used for my IAM role, and with some brute-force effort on my IAM roles' name, that person can easily gain temporary credential with AdminRole.

**(added) Solution 2:**

1. I create just 1 IAM role - GoogleUserRole
2. In the policy portion, I allow write access to admin user by using their Federated userid.

I'm still new with writing AWS policies, but I think I've read somewhere that I could have this fine-grained control to the specified user(s). This could be feasible if my users based are small, but not very feasible when my user base grows.

Welcome any thoughts and advises.

Thanks.

Comment: Since your "role" only access UserRole table to determine which role is going to give to the logged in user, your "role" only need read access so it is very limited in terms of access to the services. Another thing you might consider is giving the rol "appUserTable" to the machines themselves so you do not need to write any key/secret in the app.

Comment: yep, the "role" to UserRole table only has read-only access. How do I give out role to the end user's machine? Take note that the end users are not IAM users.

Comment: Whenever you launch an AMI, you could assign an IAM role to it to determine the privileges of that machine to access AWS. If the machines which are used by the end-user are different from the "root" one (the one you use to write into DynamoDB, perhaps you do this task manually, it's ok too) , you could assign them a role (i.e. appUserTable) to read (only read) the "UserRole" table. What you get with this method is that you do not need to write the key/secret anywhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your pointer. To add on to your point, I believe I could also use IP range. This will work if the machine and IP addresses are static. Nevertheless, my main query is still on what is the best method to assign user authorization to the AWS resources

Comment: Nevertheless, I'd go with solution 1 + machine rol to avoid hardcoding credentials.